# Two different colormaps using patch command - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How Can I produce two different color maps for the following `patch`

```
N=120;   
ids = (1:N/2)';
faces = [ids, ids+1, N-ids, N-ids+1];
c = exp(-6*cos(theta))';
c2 = exp(-6*cos(pi/2-theta))'; 
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,N+1); theta(end) = [];
figure
hold on
patch('Faces', faces, 'Vertices',[cos(theta);sin(theta)]','FaceVertexCData',c, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none')
patch('Faces', 1:120, 'Vertices',1.01*[cos(theta);sin(theta)]','FaceVertexCData',c2, 'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', 'interp','linewidth',5)
axis equal
```

The idea is that each patch will have a different colormap (with colorbars as well)

[image]

Comment: This has been answered on Matlab Central with quite a few didactic examples: [How do I use multiple colormaps in a single figure?](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101346-how-do-i-use-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure). This other example uses the classic "2 superimposed `axes`" to achieve the same result: [Multiple colormaps in one axis](https://topotoolbox.wordpress.com/2018/09/13/multiple-colormaps-in-one-figure/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple colormaps in one axes by stacking them together:

```
cmapsize = 64;
colormap( [parula(cmapsize); jet(cmapsize)] );
```

Then you can set the `CDATA` property for each plot:

```
c1 = 1:cmapsize; %this uses the first colormap.
c2 = cmapsize+1 : cmapsize*2; % this uses the second colormap.
```

In your case, you just have to scale your `CDATA` so the `CDATA` for the first plot is within the range of `[1, cmapsize]` and the other `[cmapsize+1, cmapsize*2]`:

```
c = normalize(exp(-6*cos(theta)),'range')' * cmapsize;
c2 = normalize(exp(-6*cos(pi/2-theta)),'range')' * cmapsize + cmapsize + 1;
```

The full code:

```
N=120;   
cmapsize = 64;

ids = (1:N/2)';

theta = linspace(0,2*pi,N+1); theta(end) = [];
faces = [ids, ids+1, N-ids, N-ids+1];
c = normalize(exp(-6*cos(theta)),'range')' * cmapsize;
c2 = normalize(exp(-6*cos(pi/2-theta)),'range')' * cmapsize + cmapsize + 1;

figure('colormap', [parula(cmapsize);jet(cmapsize)]);
hold on
patch('Faces', faces, 'Vertices',[cos(theta);sin(theta)]','FaceVertexCData',c, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none')
patch('Faces', 1:120, 'Vertices',1.01*[cos(theta);sin(theta)]','FaceVertexCData',c2, 'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', 'interp','linewidth',5)
axis equal
```

[image]

---

## Colorbar

As far as I know, each axes can only have one colorbar. However, you can insert a spacer (white-color area) in middle of the colorbar to separate the two colors:

```
spacer = 10;
figure('colormap', [parula(cmapsize); ones(spacer,3); jet(cmapsize)]);
```

And adjust the ticks and labels:

```
f = colorbar;
ticks = linspace(0,cmapsize,5);
f.Ticks = [ticks, ticks + cmapsize + spacer + 1];
f.TickLabels = compose('%d',ticks); % or whatever your tick labels are.
```

You also need to change your `CDATA` for the second plot to avoid using the spacer area:

```
c2 = normalize(exp(-6*cos(pi/2-theta)),'range')' * cmapsize + cmapsize + 1 + spacer;
```

This is what you can get with this method:

[image]

If this is not good enough for you, you may consider overlaying one axes on top of another as suggested in @Hoki's comment ([Multiple colormaps in one axis](https://topotoolbox.wordpress.com/2018/09/13/multiple-colormaps-in-one-figure/)).

Comment: thanks, how can I display the two colorbars next to each other in the same plot?